# What are the parameters for the edge-match-restricting arcs drawn on Penrose tilings?

Tags: geometry, tiling

I would like to try generating some computer art involving Penrose tilings. I'm looking into the layouts algorithms separately, this question concerns the decoration.

Here is a schematic of P2:

[image]

No problem drawing the boundaries, but I also understand that we have to add rules as to which edges can go where. There are a few ways to represent this but the one I am interested in is this:

[image: arcs]

I assume these are arcs of circles whose centres are at the obvious points. Given the dimensions of the first figure, **what are the radii of the blue and green circles on the left and right**?

As an intuitive guess I would say $r_{blue}:r_{green}=1:\phi$ in each figure, but I would like to see how to arrive at this properly.

Also, it seems that if I increase $r_{blue}$ for the kite and decrease it for the dart that the blue arcs could be made to join for any chosen first radius, but if I did that (and changed the green radii to maintain the touch at the centre) would the green arcs still meet on the edges? If so, how would I generate the $r_{green}$s given the $r_{blue}$s?

Answer (score 1):

The specific radii are not important. What is important is that:

- the radius of the green arc in the yellow figure and the radius of the green arc in the purple figure should add up to 1 (and be different from each other);
- the radius of the blue arc in the yellow figure and the radius of the blue arc in the purple figure should add up to $\frac{1}{\phi}$ (and be different from each other).

The point is to ensure that trivial tilings (e.g. using the parallelogram from your first picture) are ruled out.